# How to use strace on Android?

Tags: android, strace, cross-compiling

I'm trying to use **strace** on *Android* platform. Since strace is not a default binary on Android, I downloaded an pre-built version on the website [[here]](http://benno.id.au/blog/2007/11/18/android-runtime-strace). But when I tried to run it on a rooted device(Nexus 7) I got the following messages:

**"syscall: unknown syscall trap 0xe8bd8008"**

It seems the strace is not working properly. So I tried to cross-compile the strace from the source, which is ***strace 4.7*** on sourceforge. I did this by following exactly the steps posted on [this website](http://muzso.hu/2012/04/21/how-to-compile-strace-for-use-on-an-android-phone-running-an-arm-cpu). When I typed "make" to build the source, the error message occurred and showed that

**syscall.c: Invalid or undefined type "struct pt_regs"**

I've been seeking solutions for a long time and still can't get it. Could anybody give me some idea on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to include struct pt_regs from ptrace.h like this: `#include <asm/ptrace.h>`

Answer (score 2):

I've added an updated description of the enviroment (OS, compiler, strace versions) I used for those steps and uploaded a precompiled package of strace 4.7 too. You should be able to do a successful compilation by replicating the same environment. Although my guess is that the OS version is not crucial ... the same instructions should work on the latest Ubuntu (or any other distribution).